# How to use multiple Jetty Endpoints?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

Is there recommended way to use multiple jetty endpoint in apache camel?

I am using below code. I am not sure if it is correct way or not.

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class CamelPocRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {

        from("jetty:http://localhost:8111/nordic/Something1")
       .to("file://{{Somepath}}/camelpoc/jetty/Something1");

        from("jetty:http://localhost:8111/nordic/Something2")
        .to("file://{{Somepath}}/camelpoc/jetty/Something2");

        from("jetty:http://localhost:8111/nordic/Something3")
       .to("file://{{Somepath}}/camelpoc/jetty/Something3");
    }

}
```

Refer: http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using multiple jetty endpoints the same way. One thing that I would recommend it's adding endpoint uri to property files.

```
from( endpoint( "{{from.endpoint.url}}" ) )
```

In my opinion you can think about these endpoints like about usual web-service with multiple operations. Each of these operations have different path. So there is nothing special.